# Determine the next available port for php built-in server to run on

Tags: bash

I wrote a script, as a facility to run `php -S localhost:$port` on next available port, as usually I have more of them running at once, and don't wanna spend time searching for the free one manually. This works well, however I am wondering would there be  a way to avoid having that `lsof` line written twice?

```
port=8000

lsof -i :$port &>/dev/null

while [ $? -eq 0 ]
do
    let port=port+1
    lsof -i :$port &>/dev/null
done

echo $port is free
echo Starting php built in server...
php -S localhost:$port -t ./
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script has a [TOCTOU race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  You should instead just *run PHP and see if it fails to bind the port*.  The [`nc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) utility is handy for telling you whether it worked.

```
port=8000
while [ $port -lt 8100 ]; do
    php -S localhost:$port -t ./ &
    if nc -z localhost $port; then
        wait
        exit
    fi
    port=$(($port + 1))
done
printf 'No ports available in range 8000-8100\n' >&2
exit 1
```

(Unfortunately, if PHP is failing to start for some *other* reason, this will loop 100 times before giving up.  To fix that you'd have to parse PHP's error messages, which is probably not worth the effort.)

Comment: Are you sure about race condition, I only check for an available port, then once it is found I run `php -S...` only once. Unless you think that in between the check and `php-S ...` some other process could sneak in occupying that port?

Comment: _some other process could sneak in_ Yes exactly.

Comment: `nc -z localhost $port` gives me 1 for `$?`, regardless of whether the port is in use or not.

Comment: @branquito That's strange, for me it exits successfully if the port is connectable.